# Save images for later use in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, save

I want to save images that user selects from the camera roll, when app exits and restart i want to show those images to user. I have searched over internet and not found much useful resource. I know I can write the image in database as blob but I dont want to do it as increases the database size. 
Is it possible to save the image path and then later use that path to access that image.

Comment: It is possible and is typically saved to the Documents or Library/Caches directory on the device.

Comment: could you provide some tutorial or code?

Answer (score 4):

**Save the Image into the DocumentDirectory**

```
NSString *imageName = "myImage.png";
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectoryPath  stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
NSData* settingsData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageData);

[settingsData writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES];
```

EDIT:

If you want to see your saved images on the iPhone/iPad (or share them) in iTunes->Apps->Documents
jut add in Info.plist "Application supports iTunes file sharing" : "YES"

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `UIImagePickerController`
 to get the media from the Camera roll

You will get the image in the delegate method

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

Here you can get the image and save is as NSData .. in a file and then retrieve back it next time

**Edit :**

to Save

```
    Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theImage,1.0);

       NSString  *imagePath = [ContentFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %d.plist",Counter]];
        NSLog(@" iamge path %@",imagePath);


        NSMutableDictionary *objectDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:data,@"data", nil];

        [objectDictionary writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```

you should be able to change these according to your needs..

Comment: That i know, I can convert the image in NSData but main issue is saving them, could you provide some code how to write image in file. Thanks